# Switching fragments

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

I need to change `Fragment` in `View pager` 
I have getItem method in `View pager` adapter

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    fragmentPosition = position;
    Log.e("PageAdapter", "Creating fragment at: " + position);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("activity", DefinedValues.images);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("type", "info");
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("page", position+ 1 + "");

    String request = Json.stringToJson(DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.clear();

    StringAsyncRetriever net = new StringAsyncRetriever();
    net.setListener(MyPagerAdapter.this);
    net.execute(request, DefinedValues.GET_DATA);
    Log.d(TAG, "got item @ " + position);

    fragment1 myFragment = new fragment1();
    return myFragment;
}
```

And I need to change it when the AsyncTask has finished to the one that shows images

There is the fragment1 class:

```
    public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

GridView gridView;
public ImageAdapter adapter;
public int position;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        //
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), position);


    if (container == null) {
        Log.e("Null container", "Null");
        return null;
    }
    //Log.e("fragment1", "fragment1 reached!");
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_fragment, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    DefinedValues.adapterContainer.add(adapter);
    //Log.d("Fragment1 adapter count: ", DefinedValues.adapterContainer.size() + "");


/*  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(DefinedValues.imageContainer.get(position).getThumbnail());
            getActivity().addContentView(imageView, vp);
        }


    });
    */


    return gridView;
}
```

So how can I add gridView to fragment only when asyncTask ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let the `ViewPager` handle the changing of fragments. You can return the correct fragment in the `getItem`. Just hide everything in that fragment and optionally render other stuff that you are doing in `FragmentDummy`. And then, pass in the fragment to your AsyncTask or get the fragment by id/tag in your AsyncTask. You can then show the correct content view in the fragment after the task finishes and hide the dummy part of the fragment.

Comment: What is `StringAsyncRetriever`? If it is a custom class, you can add a reference to the fragment and then in `onPostExecute` call some function like `fragment.onImagesReady` on the fragment and then load the images into the fragment in `onImagesReady()`